# Python surface plot in qgis2threejs

Tags: qgis, python, qgis2threejs, surface

I'm new user of QGIS and I would like to import a surface plot - made with python - in qgis2threejs but I don't know how can be done, can someone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has your research yielded? What data type has your plot? Have you installed the extension?

Comment: Hi @Erik, yes I have installed the extension and the data are in numpy array format. I haven't try anything because I don't know where to start